# Scheduling Alteryx workflows based on file write date / time

Tags: workflow, scheduler, alteryx

I've done some research and can't seem to find an answer. I want to schedule a string of Alteryx workflows based on the file write date of a group of Excel spreadsheets. From what I've read, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this but I just wanted to make sure.

Essentially, when all the required files' write date is the current day, run all the workflows. Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [CReW Macros](http://www.chaosreignswithin.com/p/macros.html) for the Conditional Runner and/or List Runner macros. Basically, create a workflow that you schedule all the time. That workflow will then conditionally run the other ones based on whatever criteria you want to use.